# OS installation through VNC

Tags: display, software-installation, vnc, operating-systems, virtualization

The only way I have to display my RPi is VNC. If the VNC is installed, it's ok.
But How can I make the installation?

Is there any OS with VNC installed by default?

Or is it possible to make the OS and VNC installation through VirtualBox and then put it on the SD?

Comment: "The only way I have to display my rpi is VNC" Please explain why the methods others routinely use don't apply in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to

1. flash an Raspbian image,
2. then create an empty file named `ssh` (`ssh.txt` will also do the job) on the boot partition of the mSD you flashed the image to. The boot partiton is FAT, so you can do this even from Windows.
3. Next, boot your Pi and `ssh` into it. There are ssh clients also for Windows. This is best done in a network with DHCPv4 server and associated DNS, so you can ssh without having to know the IP. With a quality home router, such as a FritzBox, simply do `ssh raspberrypi.fritz.box`.
4. From there on, use `raspi-config` to enable VNC.
5. Also, change the hostname using `raspi-config`, while you're at it, as do change the password.

Voila!